# Production error

Tags: silverlight, debugging, ria

I keep getting an error in my production environment but not in my development. The error is pretty severe, it occurs at different times and simply loops a display message that says something like **"Submitoperation failed, please inspect each Entity.ValidationError in EntitiesInError"**, until there are so many popupwindows that the app crashes. How can I debug this, when it's in my production environment, I really can't reporudce this error locally.

Comment: Do you have an Exception to post? That looks like a custom message, specific to your app.

Comment: where would I find the extra info? I only get the popup childwindow with that errormessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was actually caused by me having placed a submitreport method in my unhandledexception method, and although inside try{}Catch{} blocks, it continously failed out loud.